# Scare someone off TO DO/DOING/FROM DOING

Tags: meaning

> 1 Phil scared her off reading the book on witchcraft.
>
> 2 Phil scared her off from reading the book on witchcraft.
>
> 3 Phil scared her off to read the book on witchcraft.

Do you agree with my understanding.

**1 has two meanings**

a) Phil scared her off while reading the book.

b) Phil scared her off so that she didn't read the book.

**2 has one meaning**

Phil scared her off so that she didn't read the book.

**3 has one meaning**

Phil scared her off so that she started reading the book.

Comment: Seems about right, but context would help.

Comment: Meanings 1a and 3 are possible but **very** unlikely.

Comment: 3 can also mean that he scared her off in order to start reading it himself. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you scare somebody **off**, you scare them in such a way that they physically move to another location. It's a direct scare and usually involves running away.

When you scare someone and the result is that they don't do something, you scare them **away**. (Away also works for a direct scare that involves running away).

When you scare someone and the result is that they do something, you scare them  **into**.

That said:

- #1a is clear and unambiguous. Use that instead of #1.
- #1b is unlikely. Instead, you would probably say:

> Phil scared her <strike>off</strike> **away from** reading the book on witchcraft.

- #2 becomes the same as #1b
- #3 isn't correct. Instead it should probably be:

> Phil scared her **into reading** the book on witchcraft.

In general, if a sentence has more than one meaning, you should rewrite it so that it only has one meaning and is clearly understood.